# "Двойная" загрузка при помощи AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

Часто возникает потребность загружать два файла друг за другом.
Загрузку я осуществляю так:

```
 NSString *BaseURLString =...;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
...
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,                                                                                                  NSError *error, id JSON) {                                                                                                                                                                                                     NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);                                                                                               }];
```

Но, из первого файла я достаю необходимую мне информацию для второго.
Вставлять тот же код в тело этого выглядит глупо...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не глупо, если стоит такая задача, то и нужно выполнять один метод, в теле другого, ну а вообще, лучше основную часть кода вынести в отдельный метод:

```
- (void)downloadWithURL:(NSString *)url andCompletion:(CompletionBlock)block {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
               block (request, response);
       } 
       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
               NSLog(@"error");
}
```

А потом просто делать вызов методов один внутри другого, если вам действительно нужно вызывать один метод в другом.

Вызов будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[self downloadWithURL:url andCompletion:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response){
    if (response != nil){
         [self downloadWithURL:url andCompletion:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response){
          ...
       }
}}]];
```